# setTimeout() function shows wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

In my JavaScript code, inside the **setTimeout()** the value of a variable `btnIdValue` is not changing. It's showing a constant value **0**. As this iterates through the loop the value was supposed to be changing. The minimum value for `btnIdValue` is set to 1.

```
$('#clearBtn').click(function(){
    btnIdValue = $('#inputTxtBx').val();
    while( btnIdValue > 0  ){
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert(["#circle",btnIdValue].join(''));
            $(["#circle",btnIdValue].join('')).remove();
            $(["#button",btnIdValue].join('')).remove();
        }, 1000);
        alert(btnIdValue);
        btnIdValue--;
    }
});
```

I am trying to remove elements with **id**. When i issued the hard-coded values, it works.

```
$("#circle1").remove();
$("#button").remove();
```

I tried the below part inside a loop, but it removes all the elements without the desired delay and remove effect.

```
$(["#", btnIdValue].join('')).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Why would use use array and join instead of a simple `"#circle" + btnIdValue`?

Comment: Do have a look at the duplicate although it's a little hard to link `setTimeout` with the closure examples in the answer.  In your case, it's not a closure issue (so I disagree with it being a duplicate) but rather a *concurrency issue* - what your code is actually doing is `while (val>0) { val--; } $("#.."+val).remove();`  The `setTimeout` code runs *after* the val has already been set to 0.

Comment: In your code setTimeout  will execute after finishing while loop.. thats why last value of btnIdValue ie 0. setTimeout  is meaningless here.